# Alternative outcomes of P versus NP

Tags: np-complete, complexity-classes

Given what *we know*, which of the following scenarios are possible:

1. There exist algorithms which are in-fact Ptime algorithms for NP-Complete problems, but which cannot be proved to work.
2. 1. and there are no Ptime algorithms for NP-Complete problems which can be proved to work.
3. 2. and it cannot be proved that P $=$ NP.
4. P $\neq$ NP, but it cannot be proved.

Edit: To clarify, "proved to work" just means proved to have the property that it is an algorithm which solves an NP-Complete problem in Ptime for all inputs.

Comment: All of those are possible, as far as we currentlly know.